# cant run parent process after all child processes have been terminated.

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, fork

I have a program which excecutes all child processes after the parent processes after creating several fork()'s in a loop.
But instead the parent process is run before each child process is terminated.

```
im childprocess : 18389
parent process done
im childprocess : 18390
parent process done
im childprocess : 18391
parent process done
```

Here is the code how I use the fork() call

```
for (int file = 0; file < files_count; file++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        int file_loc = file + 2;

        if (pid == 0) {
            // child process
            occurrences_in_file(argv[file_loc], argv[1]);
            break;
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            // parent process
            parentProcess();
        } else {
            // fork failed
            printf("fork() failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }

    }
```

.

```
void occurrences_in_file(const std::string& filename_,
        const std::string& pattern_);
void occurrences_in_file(const std::string& filename_,
        const std::string& pattern_) {
    int my_pid;





    cout << "im childprocess : " <<  my_pid <<endl;

}
```

.

```
void parentProcess();
void parentProcess() {

    while (true) {
        int status;
        pid_t done = wait(&status);
        if (done == -1) {
            if (errno == ECHILD){

                cout << "parent process done"<< endl;
                break; // no more child processes
            }
        } else {
            if (!WIFEXITED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
                std::cerr << "pid " << done << " failed" << endl;
                _exit(1);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a child process in each iteration of the loop and then waiting for it in the same iteration. So by the end of one iteration one child process is created, it prints then exits, parent wakes from wait and it prints and thus you get the first two lines.

Similar output follow for the next iterations, hence you get two lines for each iteration of the loop and it looks like parent is executing before child but it's not.

If you want to call the parent process after all the child process have finished then do the following.

Introduce a global variable isParent which is true if the current process is the parent. Initialize it to zero

```
int isParent = 0;
```

Then in the loop, instead of calling `parentProcess()`  set `isParent` to `1`

```
for (int file = 0; file < files_count; file++) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int file_loc = file + 2;

    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        occurrences_in_file(argv[file_loc], argv[1]);
        break;
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        // parent process
        isParent = 1;
    } else {
        // fork failed
        printf("fork() failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Then after the for loop call `parentProcess` if `isParent` is set

```
if(isParent){
    ParentProcess(files_count)
}
```

Then in the `parentProcess(int numChildren)` call wait over all the child processes.

```
void parentProcess(int numChildren);
void parentProcess(int numChildren) {

while (true) {
    int status;
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < numChildren; i++){
        pid_t done = wait(&status);
        if (done == -1) {
            if (errno == ECHILD){

                cout << "parent process done"<< endl;
                break; // no more child processes
            }
        } else {
            if (!WIFEXITED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
                std::cerr << "pid " << done << " failed" << endl;
                _exit(1);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I know that it excecutes after its child. but what I try is to excecute it after all childs so the output would look like this: im childprocess : 18389 \n im childprocess : 18390 \n im childprocess : 18391 \n parent process done ...

Comment: the code you have written does not do that. As I said, this code spawns a new child in each iteration and the parent waits for that child to finish, then spawns another child in the next iteration. Also that is why `parent process done` is printed thrice instead of once. If you want to call `parent process done` printed at the end, then follow my edits